# How can I convert a RenderFragment to a specific type?

Tags: inheritance, blazor, datagridcolumn, radzen

I have a Blazor project with a custom component library based on Radzen components. One of the Radzen components I am using is RadzenDataGrid and I would like to reduce the amount of code that is currently required as I am using the component in different projects and the base is always the same. I created a custom component to replace RadzenDataGridColumn:

```
@* DataGridColumn.razor *@
@typeperam TItem;
@inherits RadzenDataGridColumn<TItem<;
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItme="TItem">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <h1>@MyTitle</h1>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   @ChildContent
@code {
   [Parameter] public string MyTitle { get; set; }
   [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}

@* Index.razor *@
...
<DataGridColumn MyTitle="Test" TItem="MyDataType" Property="Name">
   <Template Context="item">
      @item.Name
   </Template>
</DataGridColumn>
```

But I get the following error:
`Unrecognized child content inside component 'RadzenDataGridColumn'. The component 'RadzenDataGridColumn' accepts child content through the following top-level items: 'Columns', 'Template', 'EditTemplate', 'HeaderTemplate', ...`
However, I cannot put `<Template>` in `DataGridColumn.razor` because I need to access Context.
Is there a way to cast the RenderFragment to type Template? Or to access Context inside the component?
I'm still fairly new to Blazor, so please forgive me, if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using inheritance

additonal answer using inheritance. It turns out to be very simple too, but it may depend on how the RadzenDataGridColumn handles null and defaults.

```
@* DataGridColumn.razor *@
@typeperam TItem
@inherits RadzenDataGridColumn<TItem>

@* no other markup here, just call the baseclass *@
@{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }

@code {

 [Parameter] public string MyTitle { get; set; }

 protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
    // this can be made conditional with an if()
    HeaderTemplate = @<h1>@MyTitle</h1>;
 }

}
```

It's a pity but you will need `base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);`, which is using a little behind-the-scenes magic.
You can avoid base.BuildRenderTree() by inheriting in a normal .cs file instead of .razor. But then you can't write RenderFragments like `@<h1>@MyTitle</h1>`.

All parameters are inherited so the pages could still supply a HeaderTemplate. Simply overwrite it or do some logic with `is null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, you made my day! :)
For anyone interested: You can even remove the parameter `MyTitle` now due to the inheritance and use the base parameter `Title` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, your DataGridColumn both inherits from *and* embeds a RadzenDataGridColumn . That is too much, you only need one of those techniques.

```
@inherits RadzenDataGridColumn<TItem>    // 1
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="TItem"> ... // 2
```

So you have two options, inheritance *or* embedding. Both will work.

While inheritance might be a bit more efficient I think that embedding will be easier to start with. That should look like:

```
@* DataGridColumn.razor *@
@* Untested *@
@typeperam TItem;
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="TItem">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <h1>@MyTitle</h1>
   </HeaderTemplate>
  <Template>
    @Template(context)
  </Template>
  <EditTemplate>
    @EditTemplate(context)
  </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn> 
@code {
   [Parameter] public string MyTitle { get; set; }
//   [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> Template { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> EditTemplate { get; set; }

}
```

What you are doing here is to intercept the HeaderTemplate and
pass the other Renderfragments through.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I tried out your suggestion, and I had to change `Template<TItem>` to `RenderFragment<TItem>`. This is working, so thanks a lot! But my main issue is when I remove the inheritance, that I cannot use the parameters of RadzenDataGridColumn in my custom component. Can you give me advice about using inheritance instead in this scenario?

Comment: Yes that should be `RenderFragment<TItem>`, it was not fully compiler-tested. I fixed the error.

Comment: You could pass through other parameters too, but I agree that will become messy. I'll think about inheritance later today.